# Android:Save recyclerview's data to avoid network calls

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my app.When an item is clicked from `RecyclerView` it opens new activity.

New activity contains two fragments both the fragments loads data from network call.  I've used static variables to store data so that when a fragment is opened next time it will not make network call.This works fine but when i click other item from **RecyclerView** the new activity shows fragment containing data of the previously selected item as the variables are static.  How to avoid this?

Comment: `Static` variables cause a memory leak. Its better to use database.

Comment: instead of using static variables better would be using caching mechanis or Application class if you want to have some global variable!

Comment: is it ok to store loaded data in sharedPreference and on backpress clearing the shared preference.

Comment: @Androidjack No. Its not a good approach. Database will be solved issue

Answer (score 0):

If you got id, somewhere for those recyclerview items, what you can do is simply save data in SharedPreference or SQlite database with that ID and whenever you need to call it back, Call from ID itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to use Database, but if you don't want to do that or data is changing after certain time, you can use the `LruCache` class provided in android and use item id as key. This gives you control to how you want to store item as well as saving memory by removing least recently used item.